# Custom Tab Bar React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to make a tab bar like in the picture bellow, using React Navigation.

I tried some codes, but nothing worked. Some codes are from previous React Navigation Version. The really problem is make the tab bar have a margin from from bottom and both sides, and borders rounded.

Anyone can help me please?!

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

here is demo: https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/createbottomtabnavigator-%7C-react-navigation

you can use `tabBar` props to make custom [TABBAR](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar)

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

**MyTabBar Component**

```
function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',backgroundColor:"#F4AF5F",height:50,borderRadius:50,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center" }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabLongPress',
            target: route.key,
          });
        };

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityStates={isFocused ? ['selected'] : []}
            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={{ flex: 1, alignItems:"center" }}
          >
            <Text style={{ color: isFocused ? '#673ab7' : '#222' }}>
              {label}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, with that I can customize the content inside tab bar. But I can't make rounded border for tab bar and I can't make a margin between tab bar and left/right/bottom screen.

Comment: in demo project you can see the rounded border and you can make margin between tab by changing style ob TouchableOpacity in example

Comment: In demo code I can see a white background that show the limit from screen page and tab bar

Comment: you can give style properties to adjust your tabbat

Comment: I tried override this white background but no success

Comment: now you can check https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/createbottomtabnavigator-%7C-react-navigation

Comment: I forgot, sorry xD

Comment: How to add icons?

Comment: Any update on How we can add icons for tabs??

Comment: @SharadSKatre May be its too late but you can add icons by replacing text with Image, or can add view with both text and image. 

`<Image source={require("image path")} style={styles.image}  />`

Answer (score 5):

The key to this is to add the style `position: 'absolute'` to the outer `<View>` container on your custom TabBar. This will get rid of the white background issue.

Comment: No this makes the entire navbar disappear

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't appear, add it to your custom tabBar root  `<View>`
`{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, right: 0, width: '100%', height: 50 }`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without a custom bar using [screenOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#screenoptions) function and then standard styles. Like using [tabBarStyle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbarstyle) and setting position to absolute and setting margins. This provides full control of styling the bar and based on the route too when needed.

```js
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    tabBarActiveTintColor: 'black',
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'white',
    tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: 'yellow',
    tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: 'black',
    tabBarStyle: {
      position: 'absolute',
      height: 60,
      margin: 10,
      borderRadius: 30,
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    tabBarItemStyle: {
      margin: 10,
      borderRadius: 30,
    },
    tabBarIconStyle: { display: 'none' },
    tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => {
      let icon = '';
      switch (route.name) {
        case 'Home':
          icon = 'home';
          break;
        case 'Profile':
          icon = 'account';
          break;
        case 'Settings':
          icon = 'tools';
          break;
      }
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} color={color} size={24} />
          {focused && <Text>{route.name}</Text>}
        </View>
      );
    },
  })}>
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```