# Custom first render react native tab navigation

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Is there anyone knows how to set initialroute but not the part off tab.screen react navigation?
I wanna set home screen as the default screen when I open apps without selected focus from bottom tab.

[image: Like this image]

and when I press browse tab, it's display the browse page. So when I click back button, I can go to home screen as well.
[image]

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Cuz I need home screen be the default for all screen and when display home screen, no selected for tab navigation. 
Or can I use custom route navigation for this case?

Answer (score 0):

It's more involved than you would hope, but I've gotten something working by creating a custom tab bar component:

```
const CustomTabBar = ({
  state,
  navigation,
  descriptors,
  screenHiddenInTabs,
}) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate(state.routes[0].name);
        }}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          height: 30,
          width: '100%',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        }}>
        <Text style={{ padding: 5 }}>{'\u003c Back to Home'}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          height: 30,
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
          alignItems: 'center',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100%',
          bottom: 0,
        }}>
        {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
          const isFocused = state.index === index;

          const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
          const label =
            options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
              ? options.tabBarLabel
              : options.title !== undefined
              ? options.title
              : route.name;

          const onPress = () => {
            const event = navigation.emit({
              type: 'tabPress',
              target: route.key,
            });

            if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
              navigation.navigate(route.name);
            }
          };

          return route.name !== screenHiddenInTabs ? (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
              <Text style={{ color: isFocused ? 'blue' : 'black' }}>
                {label}
              </Text>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          ) : null;
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

// Pass the CustomTabBar component to the tabBar property
function YourTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => <CustomTabBar {...props} screenHiddenInTabs="Home" />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Browse" component={BrowseScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The idea here is that we don't render a tab in the tab bar for a route in the tab navigator where the route name is equal to the value of the  `screenHiddenInTabs` prop we've added.

This way if we set the `screenHiddenInTabs` prop to `"Home"`, the screen in the tab navigator associated with that route name shows up on first render, but doesn't show up as a tab on the tab bar.

This custom tab bar also implements the top bar that allows you to go back to the first screen in the tab navigator, the home screen in your case.

*Do take into account that because I've used absolute positioning in order to place a bar on the top and on the button, you might need extra margin to the screens inside the tab navigator.*

---

*I've used the custom tab bar in this answer: [Custom Tab Bar React Navigation 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071804/custom-tab-bar-react-navigation-5) as a template for the custom tab bar I've created above. I recommend looking at the answer there, because I've stripped some of the functionalities from that bar in order to make the example code less verbose*.