# How can I change items alignment of a tabbar in React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, icons, tabbar

So, it seems that default alignment is

```
alignItems: "space-around"
```

But I need to change this. I tried to add a style for a tabbar just by passing style for a Tab.Navigator like this:

```
style={{
    alignItems: "flex-start",
}}
```

Or like this:

```
tabBarOptions={{
   style: {
       alignItems: "flex-start",
   },
}}
```

and this also didn't work. How can I do so?

Comment: You can customize Tab bar Reff: [Custom Tab bar React Navigation 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071804/custom-tab-bar-react-navigation-5)